# How to find where an uninitialised value comes from in Valgrind

Tags: valgrind

I am debugging tinyscheme version v 1.41. Valgrind notes that

```
==16675== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16675==    at 0x4062C4: opexe_0 (scheme.c:2579)
==16675==    by 0x403C5E: Eval_Cycle (scheme.c:4471)
==16675==    by 0x40A3AC: scheme_load_named_file (scheme.c:4830)
==16675==    by 0x40A878: main (scheme.c:5118)
==16675== 
==16675== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

==16675==    at 0x406324: opexe_0 (scheme.c:2586)
==16675==    by 0x403C5E: Eval_Cycle (scheme.c:4471)
==16675==    by 0x40A3AC: scheme_load_named_file (scheme.c:4830)
==16675==    by 0x40A878: main (scheme.c:5118)
```

This uninitialised value is the type information inside some object. It appears that some object is being created with no type information. I would be interested to see when that memory was allocated, or if ever that location was overwritten with other uninitialised data.

Is there a way to tell Valgrind, "tell me when and where that memory was allocated"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option

```
--track-origins=no|yes           show origins of undefined values? [no]
```

instructs valgrind to give more information about the origin of undefined values.